# Bias, SE and MSE of Uniform Distribution

Tags: parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be an i.i.d.  sequence of  Uniform $(\mu,2\mu)$ and let an estimator be $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{2} \max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$. Find the
bias, SE, and MSE of this estimator.

Hint: Let $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ be i.i.d.  Uniform $(0,1)$ and $Y = \max\{U_1, \ldots,U_n\}$.

It is known that $Y$ and $(\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} - \mu)/\mu$ have the same distribution.

So, this implies that $E[Y] = E[(\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} - \mu)/\mu]$ and $E[Y^2] = E[(\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} - \mu)^2/\mu^2]$.

The first two moments of Y are given by
$E[Y] = n/(n+1)$ and $E[Y^2] = n/(n+2)$ .

Comment: Can someone please kindly help or guide me?

Comment: what doyou mean by complex-analysis? this seems to be a question about estimators...

Comment: Sorry about that. First time trying to use this domain and screwed up. Yes, it is about estimators. Any way on changing the tag?

Answer (score 1):

You've got
$$
E[Y] = \frac { (E[\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}]) - \mu} \mu
$$
and you've got $E[Y] = n/(n+1)$, so you have
$$
\frac n {n+1} = \frac { (E[\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}]) - \mu} \mu. \tag 1
$$
From that you get $E[\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}]$ and then from that you get the bias.

If you know that $\operatorname{var}(Y) = E[Y^2] - (E[Y])^2$ then you can find $\operatorname{var}(Y)$. And
$$
\operatorname{var}(Y) = \operatorname{var} \frac{\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} - \mu}\mu  = \frac 1 {\mu^2} \operatorname{var}(\max \{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}). \tag 2
$$
Hence you can find the variance of $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$.  Recall that the variance plus the square of the bias is the mean squared error.

**PS:** You said in comments "I can't seem to see how this is linked to the original question."  How it is linked to the original question is by *algebra*.

You have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(Y) & = E[Y^2] = (E[Y])^2 = \frac n {n+2} - \left( \frac n {n+1} \right)^2 \\[10pt]
& = \frac{n(n+1)^2 - n^2(n+2)}{(n+1)^2(n+2)} = \frac n {(n+1)^2(n+2)} \tag 3
\end{align}
From $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get
$$
\operatorname{var} \left(\frac 1 2 \max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} \right) = \frac {n\mu^2} {4(n+1)^2(n+2)}. \tag 4
$$
(One expects the variance to be proportional to $\mu^2$ because $\mu$ is a scale parameter.)

If we're going to use $\dfrac 1 2 \max$ as an estimator of $\mu$, then our estimator of $(4)$ will be
$$
\frac {n\max^2} {4(n+1)^2(n+2)},
$$
so we can take that to be the mean squared error.

Solve $(1)$ for $\mu$ and conclude that
$$
E\left[\frac 1 2 \max\right] = \frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\mu.
$$
That is the expected value of the estimator, so the bias is that minus $\mu$:
$$
\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\mu - \mu = \frac{-1}{2n+2}\mu.
$$
Next:
\begin{align}
\text{mean squared error} & = \text{variance} + \left(\text{bias}\right)^2 \\[10pt]
& = \frac {n\mu^2} {4(n+1)^2(n+2)} + \left( \frac{-1}{2n+2}\mu \right)^2 \\[10pt]
& = \frac {\mu^2} {2(n+1)(n+2)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Michael but I can't seem to see how this is linked to the original question.

Comment: Then maybe your problem is with algebra rather than statistics.  I'll add a postscript. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Wayne : I suppose given the way you phrased the question I should have suspected that you wouldn't see how it's linked.  You phrased it in language almost suitable for assigning homework, with nothing that looked like thoughts of your own indicating what you tried and at what point you got stuck.  Problems of this kind do require doing some routine algebra. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you Michael, yes you are right, its the manipulation of the algebra I am struggling to see.